# How to get only the nearby subset of a way's nodes

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, geo, overpass-api

I'm using the Overpass API to query Open Street Maps for nearby road segments. I am pretty sure that my query is returning *all* of the `nodes` of the nearby `way`... but I only want *nearby* `nodes` of the nearby `way`.

[In the documentation it references this problem](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Why_we_need_recursion):

> In general, you will be rather interested in complete data than just
>   elements of a single type. First, there are several valid definitions
>   of what "complete map data" means. The first unclear topic is what to
>   do with nodes outside the bounding box which are members of ways that
>   lie partly inside the bounding box.
>
> The same question repeats for relations. If you wait for a turn
>   restriction, you may prefer to get all elements of the relation
>   included. If your bounding box hits for example the border of Russia,
>   you likely don't want to download ten thousands kilometers of boundary
>   around half the world.

But I looked at the subsequent examples and didn't see the solution.

Basically, in their example, how would I restrict the elements returned to those strictly in the bounding box (rather than returning the whole boundary of Russia)?

My current query is

```
way (around:100,50.746,7.154) [highway~"^(secondary|tertiary)$"];
>;
out ids geom;
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to change it to `node (around:...)` and then recurse upwards to the `way` to query for the highway tag but I'm not sure if I am even on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's even a bit more complicated, as you need the set intersection of all nodes in a 100m distance and those nodes belonging to one of the relevant ways. Here's how your query should look like: Adjust distance, tags for ways as needed.

Note that depending on the tagging, there's no guarantee that you will find a node in a certain distance, especially if roads tend to be rather straight and longish. This for sure will impact your results, so a bit experimenting with a suitable radius is probably needed.

```
// Find nodes up to 100m around center point 
// (center is overpass turbo specific for center point lat/lon in current map view)
node(around:100,{{center}})->.aroundnodes;

// recurse up to ways with highway = secondary/tertiary
way(bn.aroundnodes)[highway~"^(secondary|tertiary)$"]->.allways;

// determine nodes belonging to found ways
node(w.allways)->.waynodes;

( 
// determine intersection of all ways' nodes and nodes around center point  
  node.waynodes.aroundnodes;  
// and return ways (intersection is just a workaround for a bug)  
  way.allways.allways; 
 );
out;
```

check it out in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hPV